# Scroll infinito para móvil con jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

he hecho un scroll infinito que funciona perfectamente para ordenador pero no funciona en móviles, mi código es el siguiente:

```
var page = 2;
var enableScroll = true;
var $container = $('.main-panel');
$container.scroll(function(e) {
  if (enableScroll === true && $container.scrollTop() === $container.prop('scrollHeight') - $container.height()) {
    $.get("/usuario/conversacion/mensajes-next/?pagina=" + page + "&con=" + $("#id_conversacion").val()).done(function(data){
        if(data == ''){
            enableScroll = false;
        }else{
            $('.timeline li:last').after(data);
            page = page + 1;
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr){
        showPop("Se ha producido un error al cargar las agresiones. Por favor, int&eacute;ntelo de nuevo", "error");
    });
  }
})
```

El evento `$container.scroll(function(e) {` no funciona en móviles por lo que me veo obligado a usar `$(window).scroll(function(e) {` pero así los datos que arroja las variables `container.scrollTop() === $container.prop('scrollHeight') - $container.height()` no son los adecuados, por lo que no funciona.

¿Alguien ha conseguido hacer funcionar un scroll infinito para móviles?, porque desde el desarrollador de chrome funciona en la vista móvil, pero en el móvil como tal no. Y puedo decir que he probado en 7 móviles distintos y en ninguno funciona.

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo, había que poner el evento `scroll` en el `window`. Tenía un ejemplo pero no sé donde está.

Answer (score 1):

yo en lo personal lo hago de esta manera y me funciona en móvil tambien.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var win = $(window);
  win.scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()){
      alert("El scroll ha llegado al final");
      // Aqui tu petición Ajax
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p{
height: 900px;
background: gray;
color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Escrolea hasta el final</p>
```

Esta es mi app con apache cordova y me funciona bien espero que a ti tambien

[Link Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.hectorlara.peliculasgratis)
[image: App Peliculas Completas]

Comment: En mi caso no funciona. win.scroll no hace absolutamente nada en escritorio, solo se ejecuta en móvil. Además, $(document).height() y win.height() tienen el mismo valor, por lo que siempre se ejecuta la llamada AJAX.